# SSRS Multi Select Parameter keyboard search working in VS but not in Report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In a SSRS report, i have a multi select parameter, when typing through Keyboard the parameter selection is working in Visual Studio, but when i open report from report server, the key board typing and parameter selection is not working in multi select parameter in report.

Answer (score 0):

I might try deleting the report from report server and re-deploying.  In 2008 there are sometimes issues with parameters where this seems to be the only solution.